# sending a facebook_question to other users

Tags: facebook, sdk

With Facebook, I can successfully send a question to myself using `/me/questions?question=question&options=["answer1","answer2"]`.

But I can not send a question to another user. With another user's ID instead of "me" I get an error:

```
{
    "message": "(#240) Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 240
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a token that incorporates the publish_stream permission for the specified user id. See:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#questions

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. I can successfully post on another user wall using: ?PROFILE_ID/feed, it also requires publish_stream permission.